# Is it possible to perform a partial roll out in the Chrome web store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033335/private-beta-testing-a-chrome-extension#comment48528276_23033717) mentions a partial roll out in Chrome Web Store. Where can I find that feature? My extension has more than 8,000 users but I don't see any partial roll out feature and I'm afraid to send the next version to all users at the same time.

Comment: Updated my answer with actual documentation link I stumbled upon by accident

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<del>I don't think it's documented *anywhere*.</del> **And I was wrong!**

Documentation link: [Control how fast your app reaches users](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#control-how-fast-your-app-reaches-users).
In CWS lingo this is called "Controlled Rollout".

> If you don’t see the max deploy percentage control, it may be because of the following:
>
> - You have less than 10,000 users. Currently the “controlled rollout” feature is only available for items with at least 10,000 users.
> - You need to upload a newer (higher) version of a package to use the “controlled rollout” feature. We can’t apply a controlled rollout to an already published package, because it may have already reached 100% of users.

It should show on the Edit page **after** you upload a new version that's not published yet. Here's [a mention of it](https://plus.google.com/+MartinMatysiak/posts/DJE5ktYmPwM) and how it should look:

[image]

Also, I've never actually tried using it.

**Update:** In the new Webstore Dashboard it's called ["Partial Rollout"](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/update#partial-rollout) and has the same 10k users requirement.

Comment: This does not seem to be available in the new dashboard.

Comment: It is there in the new dashboard if you have over 10,000 7-day active users https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/update#partial-rollout